# SetWindowPos Z reordering arbitrary failing

Tags: google-chrome, winapi, z-order

I am building an app which shows a transparent overlay on top of the other apps. I display some extra information in that overlay. Whenever I detect that the app with the overlay received a focus from user (i.e. window was clicked), I check if my overlay window is on top and if it is not, I move the app under the overlay in the Z order, so my overlay is on top and the original app still has keyboard/mouse focus.

This works great for all the apps except for the Google Chrome. For Chrome it works fine for some time, but after arbitrary time, my watchdog can no longer put Chrome under my overlay. SetWindowPos that worked before fails to re-order windows in Z Order. Calling SetWindowPos *does not* return an error.

Any ideas why Google Chrome is so special about Z Ordering?

Comment: I would suggest moving your overlay window above the app window rather than trying to move the app window below the overlay, because the app window can contain code to prevent whatever it is you are trying to do.

Comment: Just a wild guess: While you are playing Z-order games then maybe so does Google Chrome. At any rate, you need to further investigate **how** your application fails. You can determine your window's relative position calling [GetNextWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633509.aspx). You can add this to your diagnostics code, or write a debugger extension that can be used from the debugger's *Immediate Window*. If you are not using *Remote Debugging* already, you should consider doing so, either with a remote device or a virtual machine.